# how to get the im_marked event on slack API

Tags: api, events, slack, rtm

I am developing a bot with the slack RTM API. I want to catch `im_marked` events.

My problem is that the RTM API does not receive any event when a user checks his private channel with the bot, with unread messages. I already tried with two different libraries.

I guess I am not looking at the right stage or I do not have the right use case. In what context do the RTM receive the im_marked event ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't see `im_marked` for other users. From [the `im_marked` documentation](https://api.slack.com/events/im_marked):

> The `im_marked` event is sent to all open connections for a user when
>   that user moves the read cursor in a direct message channel by calling
>   the [im.mark API method](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.mark).

I believe the main use case for this event is to build a Slack client. There, you may need to know if the user read a message via another client.